# Cron call to script giving errors, while executing script normally doesn't

Tags: linux, bash, python, script, cron

I have been having problems with executing a script every second with Cron.

This is in my cron file: 
`* * * * * /var/webconfig/test.sh`

and this in my test.sh :

`#!/bin/bash 
cd /root/python-example && pipenv run python3 tryPython.py >> /var/webconfig/log.txt 2>&1`

When I execute the script normally the code works fine, while when I call it from cron the output is: `/usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'tryPython.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

Comment: Try using a full path to the Python script e.g. `/full/path/to/tryPython.py` rather than just `tryPython.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Add user ID to run the script as, simply add 'root ' before the command line.

```
* * * * * root /var/webconfig/test.sh
```

cat /etc/crontab

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```